# VMs says out of disk space when there is a lot of space still available on the VM

Tags: azure, ubuntu, virtual-machine, storage

I am using an ubuntu vm on microsoft azure. I am facing a problem with creating new files and data being stored in database. It is throwing an error which says vm out of space. When i run  `df -h --total` output in vm is
[image]

I have also checked my azure portal which says,

[image]

I am confused because looks like my vm has space but I am not able to utilize it. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You seem to be using "memory" and "[disk] space" interchangeably. Also, you have not posted the error message itself, nor what you were doing when it popped up.

Comment: @Amadan If I delete some old files, I am able to add more files. I think the issue is with disk space not memory.

Comment: While "external memory" and similar phrases do encompass all kinds of storage, typically, unqualified "memory" refers to RAM.

Comment: sorry, clearly serverfault question

Comment: Do you solve the problem? If yes, please add an answer to display the solution.

Comment: not yet, will add an answer once it gets resolved - @CharlesXu

Comment: OK, then where do you store the files? I see your `/` space already get exhausted.

Comment: That's the problem I am facing now, not able to store or create any files.

Comment: You can expand the VM OS disk to own more space.

Comment: What about the situation now? Do you try to expand the disk and what is the result?

Comment: I have deleted few unnecessary things from `/` folder. 12 GB space is freed.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to delete the unnecessary things and then it's OK? What about later if the same issue comes again? You can try the way I provided. In addition, you could @ me if you give messages to me.

Comment: You mean expanding the OS disk ? I think thats  a costly operation. Instead I think I should try mounting on to different data drive @CharlesXu

Comment: Yeah, the expansion will cost more. If you care about the cost of the VM, then delete unnecessary things is ok. But more data disk is also cost more.